# Simulate a form in a dialogbox in Lotusscript and update calling document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

This is an issue in a Notes client application, not web app.

Classic case of a subform, opened in a dialogbox, used to enter part of the data required on the main form.  The problem is that on that subform, there are links that open views (and yes, they are required) and it seems you can't open views while in a dialogbox.

So I converted my subform to a form and now what I want to do is to open that "subform" from the uidoc and bring back all values from the "subform" into the main document.

The main document is not saved.  How can I get a handle on the "opening" document from the "subform" so I can pass values along?  Or any other way to do this (field exchange, or what have you)?  Ideas are welcomed...

Comment: So you don't use @DialogBox or equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically this is very easy

You define a global variable in your form (or better a Script- Library that you use in the forms Global Options).

Dim uidocOpener as NotesUIDocument

Then in the "Initialize"- Event of the new Form you set that:

```
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Set uidocOpener = ws.CurrentDocument
```

In that event the new document is not yet open, so CurrentDocument returns the "last" open document (that is your opener).

When saving / closing you then can update fields in the "opener" document as simple as

```
Call uidocOpener.Document.Replaceitemvalue( "YourItem", Source.Document.Getitemvalue( "YourItem" ) )
```

But take care: You need to monitor if the opener is still open and make sure somehow, that the user does not edit it while the other window is open, as it does not block the gui as a Dialogbox would.

Comment: I tried that but I didn't think of initializing the opener in the initialize event of the "dialog box" form.  Cool!  And not being modal is also a good thing as this was also a concern for my  clients as they need to validate info in other apps whil filling the form.

Answer (score 1):

One thing we do (and unfortunately I can't take credit for this, but...)  In the "calling form"

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim ws As New notesUiWorkspace
    Dim parent As notesUiDocument
    Dim newui As NotesUIDocument
    Set parent = ws.currentDocument
    Set newui=ws.composeDocument("" , "" , "NewLogEntry")
    Call parent.Close(True)
    Call newui.Refresh
End Sub
```

This opens the new "dialog" and closes the original form so that the user doesn't get confused.

Then in the "dialog", there's a field called "WorksheetID" (which is the calling form) whose formula is

```
temp:=@InheritedDocumentUniqueID;
@Text(temp)
```

Then the "close" or "process" or whatever button has (a) A way to gain access to the original document (with the inherited UNID), and (b) all the information on the "dialog" for to add to that document.

Comment: Great and simple solution, but initializing the opener in the "dialog box" form is what I prefer as I am not closing the calling form and will need to update it when the "dialog box" form closes.  But your solution is great for backend processing!

Comment: The reason the calling form is closed is that we found people would open the "dialog" but before closing the dialog, they would click the calling form, make changes there and create a huge mess, or else get very confused... "I made changes, but the changes got lost!"

Comment: To prevent that, I used a layer in the calling form that simulates the disabaled state of a form, just like on the web.  I grabbed a demo for that here : http://www.bizzybee.be/da-honey-pot/ (layers demo)